# Connecting to TFS Programmatically - Error: A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: vb.net

I have the following code which used to work and now no longer works:

```
collectionUri = New Uri(txtServerName.Text)
Dim tpc As New TfsTeamProjectCollection(collectionUri)
workItemStore = tpc.GetService(Of WorkItemStore)()
teamProject = workItemStore.Projects(txtProjectName.Text)
```

When my application hits the line: `workItemStore = tpc.GetService(Of WorkItemStore)()` I get the following error:

ArgumentException occurred

A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information:

> Requested value 'Information' was not found.
>
> {System.ArgumentException: Requested value 'Information' was not found.     at System.Enum.EnumResult.SetFailure(ParseFailureKind failure, String failureMessageID, Object failureMessageFormatArgument)}

I have uninstalled and re-installed Visual Studio 2013 ... same results. I have tried the application on another computer and it works just fine so I know my code is good.

I haven't touched this app in a few months so I'm not certain what would have changed. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to clean the cache folder on your computer? The folder path is: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache. Also you can try to start Visual Studio in safe mode (devenv /SafeMode) to see whether the issue persists.

Comment: Cece, Thanks for your feedback. I tried your suggestions and still get the same results when I run the app.

Comment: Try resetting settings and add-in settings (devenv /ResetSettings) and (devenv /ResetSkipPkgs), try rebuilding all templates (devenv /setup).

Comment: @V.Palhories, how about you create a totally new VB project to host above code?

Comment: Resetting my setting (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247075(v=vs.100).aspx) to their default did the trick. Thank you for your feedback.